# Xpath, use two queries to return two pieces of information instead of both together

Tags: xpath

I am trying to write two xpath queries to get 2 bits of info separately from 2 divs. Problem is, I only seem to get them both together.

I have tried variations of:

```
//a[@data-role='sku']/img/@title
```

This returns both "orange" and "pink"

But what I want is 2 separate queries, like:

```
//a[@data-role='sku']/img/@title[1] - orange

//a[@data-role='sku']/img/@title[2] - pink
```

Code below:

```
<ul id="j-sku-list-1" class="sku-attr-list util-clearfix" data-sku-prop-id="14" data-isselect="true">
                                                                                                                             <li class="item-sku-image"><a data-role="sku" data-sku-id="350852" id="sku-1-350852" title="orange" href="javascript:;" class=""><img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1GIlhkL6H8KJjy0Fjq6yXepXa3/Ahagaga-2018-Spring-Summer-Rompers-Woman-Jumpsuits-Fashion-Floral-Print-Loose-Sexy-Women-Playsuits-Regular-Casual.jpg_50x50.jpg" title="orange" bigpic="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1GIlhkL6H8KJjy0Fjq6yXepXa3/Ahagaga-2018-Spring-Summer-Rompers-Woman-Jumpsuits-Fashion-Floral-Print-Loose-Sexy-Women-Playsuits-Regular-Casual.jpg_640x640.jpg"></a></li>
                                                                                                                                                             <li class="item-sku-image active"><a data-role="sku" data-sku-id="1052" id="sku-1-1052" title="pink" href="javascript:;" class=""><img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1D916jkfb_uJjSsrbq6z6bVXaT/Ahagaga-2018-Spring-Summer-Rompers-Woman-Jumpsuits-Fashion-Floral-Print-Loose-Sexy-Women-Playsuits-Regular-Casual.jpg_50x50.jpg" title="pink" bigpic="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1D916jkfb_uJjSsrbq6z6bVXaT/Ahagaga-2018-Spring-Summer-Rompers-Woman-Jumpsuits-Fashion-Floral-Print-Loose-Sexy-Women-Playsuits-Regular-Casual.jpg_640x640.jpg"></a></li>
                                                                                    </ul>
```

Comment: what is the issue with your current *2 separate queries* ?

Comment: I want two queries, so I can keep the colours separate. "orange pink" is not a colour, I want to return them separately. One query for each colour.

Answer (score 1):

Index elements, which contains images, not titles:

```
//a[@data-role='sku'][1]/img/@title

//a[@data-role='sku'][2]/img/@title
```

Or titles, but out of all range of titles:

```
(//a[@data-role='sku']/img/@title)[1]
(//a[@data-role='sku']/img/@title)[2]
```

Your query `//a[@data-role='sku']/img/@title[2]` won't work, as it searches images that has second title, but all your images have only 1 title, I suppose)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either.  This //a[@data-role='sku']/img[1]/@title returns both colours.

Comment: If you have several //a[@data-role='sku'] elements, iterate by them) I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the source document, so we're guessing slightly, but I suspect it should be

```
(//a[@data-role='sku']/img)[1]/@title
(//a[@data-role='sku']/img)[2]/@title
```

Remember that subscripts bind more tightly than "/", so `a/b/c[1]` means select every `a/b/c` where the c is the first child of the corresponding `b`; if you want the first `a/b/c` overall, you need `(a/b/c)[1]`.

This means it never makes sense to put `[1]` (or any other subscript) immediate after `@title`, because there cannot be more than one `@title` selected.